# http to https infinite redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, redirect

I am using ZenCart and trying to ensure HTTPS onto my website. I have used the following in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But I still get an infinite redirect error

In ZenCart and the configure files I have tried making both

```
HTTP_SERVER
HTTPS_SERVER
```

The HTTPS but it has no affect

I'm unsure how to force people when they enter my website at http://example.com to go to https://example.com as any .htaccess code I use causes an infinite redirect

There are no other redirects set-up and this is the only piece of code in my .htaccess file

Comment: Is `RewriteEngine On` defined somewhere else?  In doubt, add it here.  Other than that, this configuration is ok.  Are you certain nothing else is redirecting?

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid using .htaccess redirects.

in your zen-cart configure.php files, ensure that the HTTP_SERVER and HTTPS_SERVER are both set to:  https://yoursite.com.  you can then add the 3 files contained in this PR and it should work fine:

https://github.com/zencart/zencart/pull/1525/files